# Convert cell to array in matlab

Tags: matlab, number-formatting

I have a certain cell of size 400x1. It basically  consists of numbers in the form of string. I mean when I do

```
mycell{1}
```

it gives result `'1'`

So you can see the number 1 is in the form of string. How can I convert this into a numeric array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this if the `size(mycell)` is 400x1 . . . . .

```
str2num(cell2mat(mycell))
```

... or like this if the size is 1x400

```
str2num(cell2mat(mycell'))
```

However, this will cause problems if any of your strings contain a different number of characters, i.e.

```
mycell{1} = '2'
mycell{2} = '33'
```

If you have a case like this,

```
str2double(mycell)
```

...seems to handle this ok as mentioned in the other answer!

Answer (score 7):

```
str2double(mycell)
```

Provided that you have an array of things that look like doubles:

```
>> c = {'1' '2' ; '3' '4'}

c = 

    '1'    '2'
    '3'    '4'

>> str2double(c)

ans =

     1     2
     3     4

>> whos ans
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  ans       2x2                32  double
```

If you have something that doesn't look like a double, you'll get a `NaN` in that cell in the result:

```
>> c{2,2} = 'aei'

c = 

    '1'    '2'  
    '3'    'aei'

>> str2double(c)

ans =

     1     2
     3   NaN
```

Comment: +1 -> This is more general than the original part of my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Also you can try `cellfun(@str2num,mycell)`
If you have a cell array of doubles:

`mycell = {'1.56548524'; '1.5265'; '-4.2616' ;'-0.2154' ;'2.15'};`

you can try

`mat = cellfun(@str2num,mycell)`